# Get directory name in input field

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have some specific questions that I still haven't found any material on forums that could help me.

I need to get the name of the folder I select to upload. I know that for security reasons I can't get the full path, but I would like to get at least the name of the folder I selected. Example:

```
<input type="file" id="fileToUpload" webkitdirectory directory/>
```

When selecting a folder, I want to get its name, I don't care about the name of the files inside it, only the folder name. Another problem would be that I also need to get the name even if the selected folder doesn't get any files.

EDIT:

```
<input type="file" id="FileUpload" onchange="selectFolder(event)" 
 webkitdirectory mozdirectory msdirectory odirectory directory 
 multiple />


<script type="text/javascript">
function selectFolder(e) {
var theFiles = e.target.files;
var relativePath = theFiles[0].webkitRelativePath;
var folder = relativePath.split("/");
console.log(folder[0]);
}
</script>
```

With this code below I get what I want, which is the name of the selected folder, but if the selected folder doesn't have any content inside it doesn't return anything.

Comment: As per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory) the `FileList` does not contain entries for directories, but only files.  So if your selected directory is empty, you won't have any entries. If, on the other hand, you have at least one file in your directory, you can get the *relative* path of that file with respect to your selected directory via `webkitRelativePath` property. But you won't get the absolute path on the local drive, as that would be a security issue.

Comment: As in my previous comment: It is **not possible** to get the name of an empty folder, because the `e.target.files` will only contain entries for *files*  but not *folders*. Thus for a empty folder it will not contain any elements you can get information from.

Answer (score 0):

does this solve your question

```
  <body>
    Hello world

  <script>
    function get_name(){
      var check = document.getElementById("fileToUpload").value;

      const arr = check.split("\\");
      console.log(arr);
      console.log("Is this your folder : " , arr.at(arr.length -1) );
      console.log(check);
      

    }
    </script>
    <input type="file" id="fileToUpload" onchange="get_name()" webkitdirectory directory />


    
  </body>
```

Comment: No, I edited the question and added some sample code that I got for now.

Comment: @LucasFernandes you can split `check` by `\\` and grab the last value which is the folder name

Comment: @Wedd I've tested your code, but when the directory I'm testing is empty, it doesn't return anything